# Can you reset perks and stats in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

Is there any way to **re-spec perks and stats** during the game in Cyberpunk 2077?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Patch 1.3 (released Wednesday, August 18th, 2021) came with the following update:

> Added a button which allows to reallocate the distribution of Perk points on a character's skill tree.

This ability costs 20,000 Eurodollars:

[image: 20K price shown on the Reset Perks option]

You can access this option from the Character menu. I don't know if they removed the Tabula E-Rasa chip from the game with 1.3; haven't played that far yet.

---

Original Answer:

You can re-spec your perks but not your attributes (so far--this could change in an update).

To re-spec your perks, you need to buy a single-use 'progression' shard from any Ripper Doc. These are 100,000 eddies, though, so start saving!

The shard is called a "Tabula E-Rasa" (clever play on words, that), and here's what one looks like:

[image: Tabula E-Rasa image]

Comment: What's actually the word play here? "E-rasa" part is clear. But I do not get the "Tabula" part. :)

Comment: "Tabula Rasa" means "blank slate" (though not literally) and is Latin. "Tabula E-Rasa" is a double entendre that means both "electronic blank slate" ("E-" is short for "electronic") *and* "erasing" (Erasa -> "Eraser" but with some slang accent). At least, that's how I read it... it may not have been intended by the developers to mean both, but if so then it's even better :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117393/discussion-between-tylerh-and-carl-fredrik-nyberg-brodda).

Comment: @TylerH - Do you know if this item is one-time-use or reusable? If one-time-use, do the ripperdocs restock it?

Comment: @Johndt They are one-time use, but I don't know if they restock over time. I imagine yes, but haven't played long enough to encounter that need.

Comment: @Johndt It's a expensive item that's mostly useful for undoing past build mistakes.  How many of them would you expect to need?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to re-spec both perks and stats. However this approach will also reset the experience gained for each individual perk category and needs quite some effort.

Therefore you will need the Mod: [Cyber Engine Tweaks](https://wiki.cybermods.net/cyber-engine-tweaks/) (you can also find the corresponding Github repo [here](https://github.com/yamashi/CyberEngineTweaks))

You can find the installation guide [here](https://wiki.cybermods.net/cyber-engine-tweaks/setting-up/installing)

The Mod provides a console that can be opened with a key that depends on your keyboard language:

- English - USA: **~** (tilde)
- German - German: **ö**
- French - France: **ù**
- Italian - Italy: **ò**
- Danish - Danmark: **æ**
- English - UK: **'**

The console is using Lua. Then in the console you can execute these commands:

1.Reset spent perk points to avoid any issues that may accompany stat changes and having perks higher than should be available.

```
Game.AddToInventory("Items.PerkPointsResetter",1)
```

2.Set a variable to count the size of your attribute point pool

```
local points = 0
```

3.Get each stat value and increase points by the difference between their value and 3
Alternately get the player's level and add 6 to it

i.e. `points = 56` is the maximum amount of skills to re-spec because 71 points is the amount of total points you can have

4.Set each ability and its related skills back down to 3
We want to avoid discrepancies between Attribute level and skill level.
If the player doesn't wish to lose skill levels, sucks to be them. They'll have to set them manually later using `SetLevel()`

```
Game.SetAtt("Cool",3)
Game.SetLevel("ColdBlood", 3)
Game.SetLevel("Stealth", 3)

Game.SetAtt("Reflexes",3)
Game.SetLevel("Gunslinger", 3)
Game.SetLevel("Kenjutsu", 3)
Game.SetLevel("Assault", 3)

Game.SetAtt("TechnicalAbility",3)
Game.SetLevel("Crafting", 3)
Game.SetLevel("Engineering", 3)

Game.SetAtt("Intelligence",3)
Game.SetLevel("Hacking", 3)
Game.SetLevel("CombatHacking", 3)

Game.SetAtt("Strength",3)
Game.SetLevel("Athletics", 3)
Game.SetLevel("Demolition", 3)
Game.SetLevel("Brawling", 3)
```

5.Give out the attribute points

```
Game.GiveDevPoints("Attribute", points)
```

Found the script in the corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/yamashi/CyberEngineTweaks/issues/265#issuecomment-750768195)

However this approach still requires a lot of manual work and I am looking forward for functionality that automates the task of reading the users level to automatically reset the attribute/stat points with one script instead of that many console commands.